# Android: Bottom Navigation stuck when selecting certain menu

Tags: android

I have 4 menu for my Bottom navigation HOME | APPLICATIONS | SAVED | INFO

I have no problem selecting the HOME, APPLICATIONS and INFO.

now when I am selecting SAVED, the bottom navigation seems to be stuck and I am not able to select other menu.

here is the code for

**SavedFragment**

```
public class SavedFragment extends Fragment {
private FragmentSavedBinding binding;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = FragmentSavedBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();
    ListView fileNameList = root.findViewById(R.id.listViewFiles);

    ArrayList<String> filenames = new ArrayList<>();

    File directory = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "");
    File[] files = directory.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xls"));

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    {

        String file_name = files[i].getName();

        filenames.add(file_name);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filenames);

    fileNameList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    
    
    return root;

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // TODO: Use the ViewModel
}
}
```

And this is

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ActivityMainBinding binding;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_applications, R.id.navigation_saved, R.id.navigation_info)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);
}
}
```

I will also attach the cml files

**bottom_nav_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_home" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_applications"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_applications" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/placeholder"
    android:title="" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_saved"
    android:icon="@drawable/baseline_save_alt_24"
    android:title="@string/title_saved" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_info"
    android:icon="@drawable/baseline_info_24"
    android:title="@string/title_info" />

</menu>
```

and finally
**mobile_navigation.xml**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:name="com.cremcash.eloan.ui.home.HomeFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_applications"
    android:name="com.cremcash.eloan.ui.applications.ApplicationsFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_applications"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_applications" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_saved"
    android:name="com.cremcash.eloan.ui.saved.SavedFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_saved"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_saved" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_info"
    android:name="com.cremcash.eloan.ui.info.InfoFragment"
    android:label="@string/logout"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_info" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: I have not found any issue with the above code, maybe SavedFragment contains the issue. Can you give the full implementation of SavedFragment?

Comment: @viethoang well I only displaying a listview in savedfragment. but yes I will edit my question